# Is Dropbox a valid quick-and-dirty source control solution?

Tags: version-control, dropbox

I see many CS students who use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) as an alternative to *real* SC systems due to its ease of use.

Do you use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) as a quick-and-dirty source control solution? Is this a valid use for it?

Comment: I'm impressed that CS students are even aware of source control.

Comment: @Dolph Do you say this because many don't use it, or have times changed in the past 8 years?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not really, but Dropbox in concert with [GIT](http://git-scm.com/download), maybe.  For a single developer scenario where you want to work on more than one development machine, I think this would work just fine.

Comment: +1 Dropbox and git sounds like a very good combination actually. Saves having to open source your project, and you don't even have to remember to push!

Comment: Or any other DVCS ;) Only thing to watch out for is possible file locks by Dropbox that cause issues with your VCS.

I tend to keep a repository in Dropbox, do work in a clone elsewhere, and push to dropbox to distribute. Of course you have to remember to push!!

Answer (score 4):

I think as a quick and dirty approach, yes, it's fine. What everybody seems to not realise is that Dropbox does save the history of your files.

You wouldn't be able to easily go back to a previous project state though, just a previous state of individual files.

So yes, if you want VERY quick and VEEERRRRY dirty, then go for it.

Answer (score 3):

The Linux kernel was developed via patch files for a long time and it worked.

I'd say any solution that works is "valid" - whether it is recommended, good practice etc is another matter entirely. I'd point them to github, set up a git server (very easy to do) or an SVN server, personally. I'd also ask for their commit log.

Answer (score 0):

Not Source Control, maybe just a Source Backup

Answer (score 0):

I store my svn repository in a DropBox folder, which is a quick and dirty way to work on multiple computers without setting up a proper SVN server.

This **only** works if two people don't use it on different computers at the same time (it *will* get corrupted)

Answer (score 0):

No. Free source control hosting is widely available - dropbox isn't quicker than git or mercurial, although it is dirtier.

You might as well use RCS locally as use dropbox.