# Revision/Source control feature in DropBox

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, dropbox, version-control

I'm looking for a webbased solution like DropBox or a solution to integrate with DropBox where I can control the files like Microsoft Visual SourceSafe a check in/out system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to version control code with a web-based interface, suggest you check out [github](http://github.com) (git) and [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com) (subversion). They are hosted solutions, like dropbox but they have the features you will need to version control source code.

If you're desperate to try and use dropbox for source code control, it's been asked before. Try searching stackoverflow for questions on dropbox like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262190/is-dropbox-a-valid-quick-and-dirty-source-control-solution).

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the topic you've posted but it doesn't seem to give me what I'm looking for.

Comment: I use dropbox myself, it keeps files synchronised across my computers. It's not a version control system and doesn't support check-in/check-out semantics, as far as I know. If you want something that does version control (like source safe) that lets you get at your files over the internet (like dropbox), I suggest solutions like the ones I've mentioned might meet your needs.